# PHP How to extend a class without override

Tags: php, web

For example if I had this code:

```
class a {
  function __construct() {
    echo "hello";
  }
class b extends a{
   function __construct() {
      echo "world";
   }
}
```

I want it to output "Hello World". Instead class A constructer is overrided by class B constrcter so will output "world" only.

Comment: `parent::__construct()`

Comment: That's the desired effect. If you want to "complement", you can call the parent function

Comment: Sidenote: You have a missing quote in `echo "world;` which should read as `echo "world";` - That will throw a parse error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- There are many more syntax errors in this example. For instance, the keyword `function` is missing in front of both constructors, and the `{` and `}` don't balance.

Comment: Yes, I spotted those as well and mentioned it in `DickW's` answer also, where the errors were fixed. @IMSoP - EDIT: Braces missing below too. But I have a working copy. Wonder if I should just edit the answer or put one in lol. (Nah, I'll be nice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
class a {
  public function __construct(){
    echo "hello";
  }
}

class b extends a {
  public function __construct(){
   parent::__construct(); // this line calls the parent (a) constructor
   echo "world";
    }
}
```

The [PHP Constructors and Destructors doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) states:

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to
>   parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the
>   child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the
>   parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared
>   as private).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `public function __construct()` or `function __construct()` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well spotted. Updated the answer. The constructor is public by default, although it's a good idea to add it for clarification.

Comment: I edited your answer. Had a missing quote in `echo "world;` - It would have cause a parse error. The OP made a mistake in the question, from what I can see, which am sure you copied from. Be careful next time ;-) `+1`

Comment: Wait a minute. Your braces don't match also. Check that.

Comment: I fixed your unbalanced braces. "You owe me one" LOL! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

in class b you call the constructor of class a before the echo.

```
 parent::__construct();
```